# Long length key in QHash

Tags: qt4, qt4.7, qhash

I want to create a QHash with 64 chars key and about 1 milion records. is it possible ?
is any limit on size of key? i got conflict in records.

Answer (score 0):

The internal hash size that `QHash` uses is fixed at the size of `uint` -- usually at least 32 bits. A million record `QHash` is not a problem at all. If you're using a custom data type `T` as the key, make sure that you provide a free standing (not a class member) implementation of `uint qHash(const T &)`, as well as `bool operator==(const T& other)` or out-of-class `bool operator==(const T& first, const T& second)`.